# cURL error 60: SSL cert issue when sending email with artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I have a weird issue going on with sending emails in Laravel.

I use Mailgun and can send emails fine when users register and everything like that.

I'm beginning to play around with scheduling commands and have created a custom artisan command to get some records and send some emails for these.

However when I run this command I get an error:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

I have set up a `cacert.pem` locally and linked this successfully in my `php.ini` file which is how I am able to send emails normally.

**I don't understand why my command cannot send emails when I can send them just fine inside a controller.**

This is the code I am using for the command:

```
$reminders = Reminder::where('utcReminderDate' , '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i'))->get();

foreach($reminders as $reminder)
    {
        Mail::send('emails.test', [], function($message) {
            $message->to('me@example.com', 'Joe Bloggs');
            $message->subject('A reminder for you');
        });
    }
```

I'm wanting to get all the reminders that need to be sent and loop through them to send them out.

When I run the command to test it via command line, it spits out the error above.

Any help getting the emails to send would be hugely appreciated. I use WAMP if that makes a difference.

Comment: normally cli use different php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either modify the vendor folder `GuzzleHttp\Client` change `verify` key to `false` from `configureDefaults` method as I did in my local machine

**or**

You can read this [conversation in Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) and try downloading the `.pem` files in some of the comments.

Here are some links:

- [.pem File Download](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

After that you should edit your php.ini file accordingly:

```
curl.cainfo = "[pathtothisfile]\cacert.pem"
```

**PS:** I would just edit the vendor file, because it's much faster and not hard to realize.

Comment: I'll try modify the vendor file, as I already have the `cacert.pem` as I mentioned.

Comment: Im glad I could help :)

Comment: The php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

Apparently PHP may load a different php.ini file when it is accessed from the CLI. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

Copying my php.ini file into `C:\windows` solved the issue.

Comment: THANK YOU for this!  I've wasted DAYS trying to figure out why a cURL script was working fine when run in a normal serialized script but then would give me a certificate error when I tried to run it multiple times in parallel tasks.  It turns out that, even though my curl.cainfo is set correctlyin php.ini, the library running the asyc tasks was reading from a DIFFERENT ini file. Go figure.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$this->client = new GuzzleClient(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);
```

This works for me.