# Mailgun: Error Sending Email from Local Laravel Project Hosted on Local Server (LAN-based)

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, mailgun

I've successfully set up Mailgun on my Laravel project, and it works perfectly on my development server. However, when I try to send an email from my local machine where the project is hosted on a LAN-based local server (hopefully connected to the internet), I encounter the following error:

[image]

I'm using the same configuration that works on my development server, but it seems there's an issue when trying to send emails from the local machine.

Is there a specific configuration or setting I need to adjust to allow sending emails from my local machine on the LAN-based server using Mailgun? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305023/curl-error-60-ssl-cert-issue-when-sending-email-with-artisan-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cURL error 60: SSL cert issue when sending email with artisan command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305023/curl-error-60-ssl-cert-issue-when-sending-email-with-artisan-command)

Comment: While you're not using PHPMailer despite having tagged your question with it, the PHPMailer docs have some useful information about [dealing with verification failures and outdated CA certificate bundles](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure).

Answer (score 1):

[cURL error 60: SSL cert issue when sending email with artisan command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305023/curl-error-60-ssl-cert-issue-when-sending-email-with-artisan-command#answer-34305154)

You can either modify the vendor folder `GuzzleHttp\Client` change `verify` key to `false` from `configureDefaults` method as I did in my local machine

**or**

You can read this [conversation in Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) and try downloading the `.pem` files in some of the comments.

Here are some links:

- [.pem File Download](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)

After that you should edit your php.ini file accordingly:

```
curl.cainfo = "[pathtothisfile]\cacert.pem"
```

**PS:** I would just edit the vendor file, because it's much faster and not hard to realize.

Comment: Disabling verification is a really bad idea. Fix your server instead of hiding the problem.

Comment: @Synchro I hope you read the questions title "from my local machine".

Comment: It applies equally to your local machine. TLS without verification is largely pointless. I often see people disabling verification to avoid such errors, and it turns out it's because their traffic is being intercepted and interfered with (usually by their hosting provider) – precisely one of the things that TLS is designed to protect you against.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the mailgun/guzzleHttp looking for valid certificate (SSL issue) for security reasons.
You can solve it like below (Wamp server):

1- Download this file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and put this in `"C:/wamp64/bin/php/(your php version)/extras/ssl/"` directory

2- find all `php.ini` files (even `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development`) under this directory `"C:/wamp64/bin/php/php (your php version)"`

3- find these following parts in above `.ini` files and edit it as shown:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:/wamp64/bin/php/(your php version)/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile= "C:/wamp64/bin/php/(your php version)/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"
```

4- clear cache laravel and restart your laravel server

5- restart wamp server